# Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding

Tags: java, hibernate, utf-8, character-encoding, jersey

I am writing a REST API. I fetch data from a database and store it in a String. Then I send it back to the browser like this:

```
//fetch data from database
String s = ...

// Prepare it for browser
byte[] data = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

// Send it to browser now
out.write(data); // out is an OutputStream received from Jersey through the MessageBodyWriter interface
```

The data comes from a postgresql database with UTF8 encoding. The data is stored in a character varying(5000).

When the browser (Chrome) displays the String this error appears:

```
error on line 29 at column 285: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x19 0x4C 0x29 0x20
```

The same problem occurs on other browsers.

Here are the headers sent to the browser:

```
200
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8
```

**SUMMARY**
Here is a summary of the data flow

Database(UTF8) > Hibernate > Object > getBytes("UTF-8") > browser

What am I missing ?

Comment: @assylias how can I add the header ?

Comment: @assylias - utf-8 doesn't need a bom.

Comment: did you specify the Content-Type header when returning to the browser?  and how are you returning that "data" array.  (show more code)

Comment: Why are you sending byte[] to the browser in the first place? Don't you have something like a HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream.println(s) where you can leave encoding to someone else?

Comment: @wallenborn I use Jersey with a MessageBodyWriter. All I have is an  OutputStream, I don't have any information about the implementation behind...

Comment: Reconsider what type of data are you assigning to the string.. or mention the code where the data is stored in the String s...

Comment: What type of input stream are you using to read the data.. ObjectInputStream, DataInputStream or BufferedInputStream ??

Comment: @Abhishek Hibernate fetch the data and put it in an object for me

Comment: I wonder why your code is generating 0x19. AFAIK, 0x19 can only be an control character (EM) and won't be part of a UTF-8 surrogate.

Comment: how are you getting the bytes to the browser?

Comment: @Alex, i'm a noob in Jersey, but if the content type says it's using UTF-8 (you set it with a Produces annotation, right?) and your output is good, then string.getBytes("UTF-8") should work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem not occuring in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies at the point where you have created the string,

```
String s = ...
```

As,String objects in Java don't have an encoding.

The only thing that has an encoding is a `byte[]`. So if you need `UTF-8` data, then you need a byte[]. If you have a String that contains unexpected data, then the problem is at some earlier place that incorrectly converted some binary data to a String (i.e. it was using the wrong encoding)...
so instead of focusing on the `s.getBytes()` part, focus on receiving and storing the string properly.

Comment: Try Changing the procedure you use to stream the data in. That is, try various options: BufferedInputStream(most likely to work),DataInputStream(may work), ObjectInputStream(least likely to work).

Answer (score 3):

Based on my surprise of an `0x19` character, I suspect that the data in your database is being stored or transferred as UTF-16.

The bytes given don't give a very good sentence either in UTF-16 big endian or UTF-16 little endian so I suspect there's been an incorrect conversion before the JDBC connector which means your String s, is already polluted with incorrect data.

Check your JDBC connector, the table encoding and any other data connectors to your database.